# how to change the location of a value in a list in a hashmap in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

sorry for asking another really obvious question - I'm struggling with hashmaps..

What I want to do is change the order of where a value is stored in a list that is stored in a hashmap, and I do not want to use an iterator.

for example, there is a list of courses at a school and in each course there is a list of students. There the hall monitor job is the first student on list for a course that is picked at random. When a course is selected the student at the top of the list is then put to the bottom of the list for all the course that they are part of. There are 9 courses and and a student can appear on multiple student lists.

I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
//instance variable
private HashMap<String, String[]> qualifiedStudents;
    qualifiedStudents = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

  public void putStudentLastInRosters(String studentName)
  {
   for(String course : qualifiedStudents.keySet())
   {
      if(qualifiedStudents.get(course).contains(studentName)) 
    {
       qualifiedStudents.remove(course, studentName); 
       qualifiedStudents.put(course, studentName);
    }
  }

  }
```

Comment: Can you change the String[] to an ArrayList<String>?

Comment: sorry I should have been more precise in showing how it is initialised, the list is an ArrayList string

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your question, but perhaps you're struggling because order in Maps is guaranteed by their iterators. From the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html): "The *order* of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on the map's collection views return their elements. Some map implementations, like the TreeMap class, make specific guarantees as to their order; others, like the HashMap class, do not."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//instance variable
private HashMap<String, List[]> qualifiedStudents;
    qualifiedStudents = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

public String putStudentLastInRosters(String studentName) {
    for(String course : qualifiedStudents.keySet()) {
        List<String> students = qualifiedStudents.get(course);
        if(students.remove(studentName)) {
            students.add(studentName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the lists, not the map. So the code should be:

```
for (List<String> list : qualifiedStudents.values()) {
    if (list.remove(studentName)) {
        list.add(studentName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) for this task.

Implement your own comparator to reflect the sorting order you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to reorder the student in every list per course.

```
    for(List<String> studentsInCourse : qualifiedStudents.values()) {
        if (studentsInCourse.remove(studentName)) {
            studentsInCourse.add(0, studentName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes 100% but I want them to be at the end of the list not the first position in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it looks like you are trying to remove and put a String object from/to your HashMap when the value type of the HashMap is a String array.

Where you have:

```
   qualifiedStudents.remove(course, studentName); 
   qualifiedStudents.put(course, studentName);
```

you want to instead get a reference to the String array ("course" I believe) and move the studentName string around in that.  Like barsju said, this will probably be easier with an ArrayList than with a String array.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the ArrayList of Students in the class and allow you to perform remove and add operations. We just need to remove the studentsName, and readd it. In a linked list this will add it to the end of the ArrayList.

```
qualifiedStudents.get(course)
```

I redeclared your HashMap.

```
    //instance variable
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> qualifiedStudents = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

  public void putStudentLastInRosters(String studentName)
  {
   for(String course : qualifiedStudents.keySet())
   {
      if(qualifiedStudents.get(course).contains(studentName)) 
    {
       qualifiedStudents.get(course).remove(studentName); 
       qualifiedStudents.get(course).add(studentName);
    }
  }

  }
```